# Get title using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Puppeteer is very useful and I have been able to scrape many different parts of my site. I know its very easy easy to get by selection and xpath but how would I get by xpath or selection and print out "hey"

```
<div title="hey">spoon</div>
```

here is what I have come up with so far.

```
 let hey = document.querySelector(myPath).innerText;
```

This result returns "Spoon"
How would I get "Hey"

Comment: What's the value of `myPath` in your querySelector?

Comment: @blurfus thank you for your help. this was the solution. have an amazing day

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value of `myPath` is `'div'` -  you need to get the value of the attribute instead of the `innerText`

For example:

```
document.querySelector(myPath).getAttribute('title');
```

See demo:

```js
var myPath = 'div';

var hey = document.querySelector(myPath).getAttribute('title');
console.log(hey);
```

```html
<div title="hey">spoon</div>
```